# Fastest way to multiply X*X.transpose() in Eigen?

Tags: optimization, matrix, eigen

I want to multiple matrix with self transposed. The size of matrix about X[8, 100].

Now it looks " MatrixXf h = X*X.transpose()"

a) Is it possible to use faster multiplication using explicit facts:

1. Result matrix is symmetric
2. The X matrix use same data so, can use custom procedure for multiplication. 
   ?

b)Also i can generate X matrix as transposed and use X.transpose()*X, whitch i should prefer for my dimensions ?

c) Any tips on faster multiplication of such matrixes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Your matrix is too small to take advantage of the symmetry of the result because if you do so, then you will loose vectorization. So there is not much you can do.

(b) The default column storage should be fine for that example.

(c) Make sure you compile with optimizations ON, that you enabled SSE2 (this is the default on  64 bits systems), the devel branch is at least twice as fast for such sizes, and you can get additional speedup by enabling AVX.

Comment: Why i should loose vectorization? The multiplication can perform row per row dot products (length 100) for lower or upper matrix part. 

in pseudocode 
            for(int k =0; k < s; k++)
            {

                for(int l =k; l < s; l++)

                {

                    M(k,l) = X.row(k).dot(X.row(l))

                }

            }

Comment: Dot products are not very efficient regarding vectorization (even assuming you are using a rowmajor storage). The trick here is that you have the chance to have a 8x8 result which is just perfect for vectorization purpose. For instance, with AVX, you can compute a whole column of the result in a single fully vectorized for loop! If your result matrix was, e.g., 9x9, then this would be a different story.

Comment: Do you mean the Vector (length 8) Scalar multiplication and accumulation in result matrix, is faster to vectorize that dot product of bigger vectors (length 100)? Sounds surprising for me! BWT my main platform is ARM (NEON).